Crystal Reports: Origin of additional statements in WHERE-Clause
I have a report with a subreport. The subreport receives 3 parameters via the subreport links (firma, mandant, material_key).
Within the subreport, these parameters are mapped to their respective database fields (menu: Report/Selection Formulas/Record):
{cs_kategorie.firma}={?Pm-cs_kategorie.firma} and
{cs_kategorie.mandant}={?Pm-cs_kategorie.mandant} and
{bs_mat_texte.material_key}={?Pm-bs_mat_texte.material_key}

So far, so good.
Under Database/Show SQL-Query there are 3 additional statements in the where-clause:
SELECT bs_mat_texte.material_key, bs_mat_texte.text, cs_kategorie.mandant, cs_kategorie.firma     FROM   bs_mat_texte bs_mat_texte INNER JOIN csgwin-pap.dbo.cs_kategorie cs_kategorie ON    bs_mat_texte.typ=cs_kategorie.xkey     
WHERE  cs_kategorie.firma='605' AND cs_kategorie.mandant='001' AND bs_mat_texte.material_key=90152 AND     
bs_mat_texte.typ = 'BEM' AND 
cs_kategorie.sprache = '000' AND 
cs_kategorie.kategorie_nr = 5073

These last 3 lines have to be defined somewhere. The values are static.
But I can't figure out, where these are set.
Any advice welcome ;)
I'm using CR Version 14.0.4.738 RTM
Thank you
I looked into the formulas and the database expert and any place and formular but found nothing. I used the search in CR without any results.

If you look in Report, Selection Formula, Record... you will see that Crystal automatically creates additional filter conditions based on the subreport links.
Each subreport link becomes a parameter.
You can remove those clauses from the record selection formula.

Yes, I know, these are fine. But the last 3 lines don't show anywhere (bs_mat_texte.typ = 'BEM' AND
cs_kategorie.sprache = '000' AND
cs_kategorie.kategorie_nr = 5073)

Fixed it :)
I couldn't figure out where those 3 line come from.
But I managed to fix the problem by creating a new subreport with the same parameters.
In Report->Selection Formulas->Saved Data I put the additional conditions. In the old subreport there was nothing in the saved data section, so I couldn't alter them.
Maybe the problem occured because the report was originally created in an older version of CR and it's a conversion issue?

They were not in the 'Saved Data...' section. They were in the 'Record...' section as per my answer above.

well, no, they were not. In my original post I put the 3 lines that were in the Record section. But those 3 additional lines were not; neither there nor in the saved data section. But I rebuilt the subreport and was able to recreate the behaviour by putting those 3 additional line in the saved data section.
